# Order List by Descending Time in H:M:S Format in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I'm trying to order a list that looks something like this:

> ['2017-11-03 15:21:00', '2017-11-03 15:03:00', '2017-11-03 15:11:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:52:00', '2017-11-03 14:37:00', '2017-11-03 14:32:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:20:00', '2017-11-03 14:30:00', '2017-11-03 14:43:00',
>   '2017-11-03 14:58:00', '2017-11-03 15:58:00', '2017-11-03 15:42:00',
>   '2017-11-03 14:59:00', '2017-11-03 15:40:00', '2017-11-03 14:35:00',
>   '2017-11-03 14:21:00', '2017-11-03 15:26:00', '2017-11-03 15:50:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:13:00', '2017-11-03 15:53:00', '2017-11-03 14:40:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:16:00', '2017-11-03 14:45:00', '2017-11-03 15:33:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:35:00', '2017-11-03 15:36:00', '2017-11-03 14:23:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:10:00', '2017-11-03 15:37:00', '2017-11-03 14:54:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:44:00', '2017-11-03 15:23:00', '2017-11-03 14:47:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:43:00', '2017-11-03 14:48:00', '2017-11-03 14:41:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:45:00', '2017-11-03 15:09:00', '2017-11-03 15:06:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:08:00', '2017-11-03 14:57:00', '2017-11-03 15:17:00',
>   '2017-11-03 14:52:00', '2017-11-03 15:14:00', '2017-11-03 15:19:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:25:00', '2017-11-03 15:48:00', '2017-11-03 15:24:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:57:00', '2017-11-03 15:28:00', '2017-11-03 15:34:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:59:00', '2017-11-03 14:53:00', '2017-11-03 14:50:00',
>   '2017-11-03 14:55:00', '2017-11-03 15:56:00', '2017-11-03 15:46:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:32:00', '2017-11-03 16:00:00', '2017-11-03 15:29:00',
>   '2017-11-03 14:34:00', '2017-11-03 15:04:00', '2017-11-03 14:38:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:07:00', '2017-11-03 14:39:00', '2017-11-03 14:25:00',
>   '2017-11-03 14:51:00', '2017-11-03 14:33:00', '2017-11-03 14:46:00',
>   '2017-11-03 14:22:00', '2017-11-03 15:47:00', '2017-11-03 14:42:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:27:00', '2017-11-03 15:41:00', '2017-11-03 15:55:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:31:00', '2017-11-03 14:56:00', '2017-11-03 14:49:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:39:00', '2017-11-03 15:01:00', '2017-11-03 14:29:00',
>   '2017-11-03 14:27:00', '2017-11-03 14:44:00', '2017-11-03 15:49:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:30:00', '2017-11-03 15:51:00', '2017-11-03 15:54:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:22:00', '2017-11-03 14:31:00', '2017-11-03 14:28:00',
>   '2017-11-03 14:26:00', '2017-11-03 15:15:00', '2017-11-03 14:24:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:00:00', '2017-11-03 15:38:00', '2017-11-03 14:36:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:18:00', '2017-11-03 15:05:00', '2017-11-03 15:12:00',
>   '2017-11-03 15:02:00']

So that it looks like:

> ['2017-11-03 16:00:00', '2017-11-03 15:59:00', '2017-11-03 15:58:00' etc...]

I would like to know how I can accomplish this, but also I would be interested to know how to preemptively solve the issue by putting them in a list in order already.

I am creating the list from a json from https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo

I am just appending each item to a list like this:

```
times = []
if (interval == '1min'):
   for item in data['Time Series (1min)']:
       times.append(item)
```

But I get the earlier list and it's not in order, even though if you visit the webpage, the times are in descending order.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings aren't sorted correctly because they come from a JSON dictionary. When JSON gets converted to Python objects, the strings land in a Python dict, which isn't sorted.

You only need [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> sorted(times, reverse=True)
['2017-11-03 16:00:00', '2017-11-03 15:59:00', '2017-11-03 15:58:00', '2017-11-03 15:57:00', '2017-11-03 15:56:00', '2017-11-03 15:55:00', '2017-11-03 15:54:00', '2017-11-03 15:53:00', '2017-11-03 15:52:00', '2017-11-03 15:51:00', '2017-11-03 15:50:00', '2017-11-03 15:49:00', '2017-11-03 15:48:00', '2017-11-03 15:47:00', '2017-11-03 15:46:00', '2017-11-03 15:45:00', '2017-11-03 15:44:00', '2017-11-03 15:43:00', '2017-11-03 15:42:00', '2017-11-03 15:41:00', '2017-11-03 15:40:00', '2017-11-03 15:39:00', '2017-11-03 15:38:00', '2017-11-03 15:37:00', '2017-11-03 15:36:00', '2017-11-03 15:35:00', '2017-11-03 15:34:00', '2017-11-03 15:33:00', '2017-11-03 15:32:00', '2017-11-03 15:31:00', '2017-11-03 15:30:00', '2017-11-03 15:29:00', '2017-11-03 15:28:00', '2017-11-03 15:27:00', '2017-11-03 15:26:00', '2017-11-03 15:25:00', '2017-11-03 15:24:00', '2017-11-03 15:23:00', '2017-11-03 15:22:00', '2017-11-03 15:21:00', '2017-11-03 15:20:00', '2017-11-03 15:19:00', '2017-11-03 15:18:00', '2017-11-03 15:17:00', '2017-11-03 15:16:00', '2017-11-03 15:15:00', '2017-11-03 15:14:00', '2017-11-03 15:13:00', '2017-11-03 15:12:00', '2017-11-03 15:11:00', '2017-11-03 15:10:00', '2017-11-03 15:09:00', '2017-11-03 15:08:00', '2017-11-03 15:07:00', '2017-11-03 15:06:00', '2017-11-03 15:05:00', '2017-11-03 15:04:00', '2017-11-03 15:03:00', '2017-11-03 15:02:00', '2017-11-03 15:01:00', '2017-11-03 15:00:00', '2017-11-03 14:59:00', '2017-11-03 14:58:00', '2017-11-03 14:57:00', '2017-11-03 14:56:00', '2017-11-03 14:55:00', '2017-11-03 14:54:00', '2017-11-03 14:53:00', '2017-11-03 14:52:00', '2017-11-03 14:51:00', '2017-11-03 14:50:00', '2017-11-03 14:49:00', '2017-11-03 14:48:00', '2017-11-03 14:47:00', '2017-11-03 14:46:00', '2017-11-03 14:45:00', '2017-11-03 14:44:00', '2017-11-03 14:43:00', '2017-11-03 14:42:00', '2017-11-03 14:41:00', '2017-11-03 14:40:00', '2017-11-03 14:39:00', '2017-11-03 14:38:00', '2017-11-03 14:37:00', '2017-11-03 14:36:00', '2017-11-03 14:35:00', '2017-11-03 14:34:00', '2017-11-03 14:33:00', '2017-11-03 14:32:00', '2017-11-03 14:31:00', '2017-11-03 14:30:00', '2017-11-03 14:29:00', '2017-11-03 14:28:00', '2017-11-03 14:27:00', '2017-11-03 14:26:00', '2017-11-03 14:25:00', '2017-11-03 14:24:00', '2017-11-03 14:23:00', '2017-11-03 14:22:00', '2017-11-03 14:21:00']
```

The format is convenient, because sorting the strings lexicographically will sort them chronologically.

Comment: This is what I needed! Thanks for the quick, simple, and working answer!